# numpy 'isin' performance improvement

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a matrix with 383milj rows, i need to filter this matrix based on a list of values (`index_to_remove`). This function is performed several times during 1 iteration. Is there a faster alternative to:

```
def remove_from_result(matrix, index_to_remove, inv=True):
    return matrix[np.isin(matrix, index_to_remove, invert=inv)]
```

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad, I don't think `set` has any advantage with `np.isin`.

Comment: Do I misunderstand that `index_to_remove` is not a list of indices but a list of _values_ that are removed by your function?

Comment: @tif, yes that is correct. index_to_remove is a list of values, which are somewhere in the matrix.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad, Yep, the *output* is "roughly equivalent" but the *method* is most certainly not.

Comment: According to my experimentation, `matrix[isin(matrix,to_remove,invert=True)]` is already >50x faster than `[i for i in matrix.flat if i not in to_remove]` and `[filter(lambda i:i not in to_remove,matrix.flat)]` . That hints towards little space left for optimization. You could try improving performance by parallelizing this code, or using a faster implementation of python, e.g. Cython.

Comment: Look at the code for `np.in1d` (which `isin` uses).  For small `index_to_remove` it does `(matrix!=index[0]) | (matrix!=index[1]) | ...`. just a logical combination of boolean masks.  For larger `index_to_remove` uses `argsort` and looks for duplicates.  In this case being able to set `assume_unique=True` should help speed.

Comment: Can you post isin performance improvement without removing anything ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A faster Implementation

This is a compiled version using a set as the list comprehension solution by @Matt Messersmith. It is basically a replacement for the slower np.isin method. I had some problems with the case where `index_to_remove` is a scalar value and implemented a seperated version for this case.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def in1d_vec_nb(matrix, index_to_remove):
  #matrix and index_to_remove have to be numpy arrays
  #if index_to_remove is a list with different dtypes this 
  #function will fail

  out=np.empty(matrix.shape[0],dtype=nb.boolean)
  index_to_remove_set=set(index_to_remove)

  for i in nb.prange(matrix.shape[0]):
    if matrix[i] in index_to_remove_set:
      out[i]=False
    else:
      out[i]=True

  return out

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def in1d_scal_nb(matrix, index_to_remove):
  #matrix and index_to_remove have to be numpy arrays
  #if index_to_remove is a list with different dtypes this 
  #function will fail

  out=np.empty(matrix.shape[0],dtype=nb.boolean)
  for i in nb.prange(matrix.shape[0]):
    if (matrix[i] == index_to_remove):
      out[i]=False
    else:
      out[i]=True

  return out


def isin_nb(matrix_in, index_to_remove):
  #both matrix_in and index_to_remove have to be a np.ndarray
  #even if index_to_remove is actually a single number
  shape=matrix_in.shape
  if index_to_remove.shape==():
    res=in1d_scal_nb(matrix_in.reshape(-1),index_to_remove.take(0))
  else:
    res=in1d_vec_nb(matrix_in.reshape(-1),index_to_remove)

  return res.reshape(shape)
```

**Example**

```
data = np.array([[80,1,12],[160,2,12],[240,3,12],[80,4,11]])
test_elts= np.array((80))

data[isin_nb(data[:,0],test_elts),:]
```

**Tmings**

```
test_elts = np.arange(12345)
data=np.arange(1000*1000)

#The first call has compilation overhead of about 300ms
#which is not included in the timings
#remove_from_result:     52ms
#isin_nb:                1.59ms
```

Comment: It does not seem to work with a multidimensional matrix, e.g `data = [[80,1,12],[160,2,12],[240,3,12],[80,4,11]]`, lets say i wan't to remove all rows with 80 in the first column, it gives a numba error

Comment: @Ward Set does not work with only one value, I can correct this. So basically you want to remove rows entirely if one of the index_to_remove values is on a specified place or every time on the first place? This would be a bit different to handle. Do you only have 2d arrays or nd-arrays?

Comment: Yes, it is a matrix like the data i showed in the comment, where I get e.g `[80,160]` and know which column from the matrix to search, for example in data[:,0] and then it should leave the matrix `[[240,3,12]]`

Answer (score 3):

The runtime of your filtering function appears to be linear w.r.t. the size of your input `matrix`. Note that filtering with a list comprehension with a `set` is definitely linear, and your function is running roughly twice as fast as a list comprehension filter with the same input on my machine. You can also see that if you increase the size by a factor of X, runtime also increases by a factor of X:

```
In [84]: test_elts = np.arange(12345)

In [85]: test_elts_set = set(test_elts)

In [86]: %timeit remove_from_result(np.arange(1000*1000), test_elts)
10 loops, best of 3: 81.5 ms per loop

In [87]: %timeit [x for x in np.arange(1000*1000) if x not in test_elts_set]
1 loop, best of 3: 201 ms per loop

In [88]: %timeit remove_from_result(np.arange(1000*1000*2), test_elts)
10 loops, best of 3: 191 ms per loop

In [89]: %timeit [x for x in np.arange(1000*1000*2) if x not in test_elts_set]
1 loop, best of 3: 430 ms per loop

In [90]: %timeit remove_from_result(np.arange(1000*1000*10), test_elts)
1 loop, best of 3: 916 ms per loop

In [91]: %timeit [x for x in np.arange(1000*1000*10) if x not in test_elts_set]
1 loop, best of 3: 2.04 s per loop

In [92]: %timeit remove_from_result(np.arange(1000*1000*100), test_elts)
1 loop, best of 3: 12.4 s per loop

In [93]: %timeit [x for x in np.arange(1000*1000*100) if x not in test_elts_set]
1 loop, best of 3: 26.4 s per loop
```

**For filtering unstructured data, that's as fast as you can go in terms of algorithmic complexity, since you'll have to touch each element once. You can't do better than linear time.** A couple of things that might help improve performance:

1. If you have access to something like `pyspark` (which you can get by using EMR on AWS if you're willing to pay a few bucks), you could do this much faster. The problem is pretty embarrassingly parallel. You can split up your input into K chunks, give each worker the items that need to be flitered and a chunk, have each worker filter, and then collect/merge at the end. Or you could even try using `multiprocessing` as well, but you'll have to be careful about the memory (`multiprocessing` is similar to C's `fork()`, it'll spawn subprocesses, but each of those clones your current memory space).
2. If your data has *some* structure (like it's sorted), you could be smarter about it, and get sublinear algorithmic complexity. For instance, if you need to remove a relatively small number of items from a large, sorted array, you could just do bin search for each item to remove. This would run in O(m log n) time where m is the number of items to remove and n is the size of your large array. If m is relatively small (compared to n), you're in business, as then you'll be close to O(log n). There are even more clever ways to handle this particular situation, but I choose this one since it's pretty easy to explain. If you know *anything* about your data's distribution, you *might* be able to do better than linear time.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the arrays you are passing in np.isin as integer type if possible. Apart from that, if possible try making the comparison array (second parameter as small as possible), removing duplicates is one of the ways.