# What are some fast implementations of a "nunique" for numpy with a max count threshold?

Tags: python, numpy, unique, distinct, distinct-values

I'm sure this has a name in some other domain (maybe approx count distinct?).

Suppose you want to count the number of distinct elements in a numpy array but you only care about numbers below some threshold and above that you just return that it has more than thresh unique entries. This is particulary good for high arity arrays where you don't care that there are 10000 entries just that there are more than 10 entries perhaps.

In a compiled language this is simple to make fast. But what are some fast implementation expose to python?

Naively one might try numba like this:

```py
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def nunique_max_thresh(x, thresh=10):
    seen = set()
    for i in range(len(x)):
        seen.add(x[i])
        if len(seen) > thresh:
            return thresh
    return len(seen)
```

But the `set` usage is not supported.

Cython is an option but I am wondering if this is already done in some library or elsewhere in python. It seems like bottleneck would do this kind of thing but it's not really in there.

https://bottleneck.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html

For example, consider these kind of arrays:

```py
import string                                                                                                                                                                                              
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)                                                                                                                                                                                         
a = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), 1e7)
b = np.ones(int(1e7))
```

And you just want to know if this array has 10 or more unique values. Do not use the fact that these are length one strings.

For reference, this runs. But is probably not optimal.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def nunique_truncated(np.ndarray x_in, np.int thresh=10):
    seen = set()
    for i in range(x_in.shape[0]):
        seen.add(x_in[i])
        if len(seen) >= thresh:
            return thresh
```

Comment: a) If this is for NLP wordcounts, then use count vectorizers that suppress stopwords, map punctuation and case  b) [Bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) exist

Comment: @smci This is not that case. I'm literally just messing around with dataframes with lots of object columns. Obviously if they are pandas categoricals all the work is done already. This kind of question would come up if you want to decide whether a column should be stored in dict/categorical format.

Comment: By 'store in dict format', do you mean categorical? Else, 'stored in dict/categorical format' doesn't make sense. Anyway as I said, Bloom filters do exist, you can get fast approximations on cardinality (as well as count).

Comment: @smci yes categorical is sometimes called dict format ... I think in the arrow space maybe. But how does the Bloom filter help ... maybe I am missing something? I thought that was for large sets where you want to use less memory? This is simply a loop and a small set, and once you hit size n you break and you are done forever. It is probably fast enough in vanilla python to be honest but it is a good example problem of how to optimize from python.

Comment: ['categorical'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable) is a type of variable which can take on one of a set of values. (Whether some packages implement that using Python dict isn't hugely important).

Comment: `pandas` wraps numpy and efficiently implements [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) and [nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) on Series and DataFrames. I suggest it's what you want. If you still don't like its performance, post a tractable example ([mcve]) at whatever scale you're talking about. Seeded-random data (e.g. autogenerated strings) is fine. Btw, pandas handles categoricals fine. Unless you provide an MCVE example this question is likely to be closed as 'seeking algorithm/pkg recommendations'.

Comment: @smci Where do we post for "seeking pkg/solution recommendations"? That is exactly what I am seeking. This is a for loop with a set as posted in the example. I will add some ascii vector as an example.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that bailing out early is a *considerable* time saving? Even if using compiled code, vectorization will be *much* faster than iteration+seen-filtering – to the point that the "wasted" operations of vectorization will likely still be faster than the "bloat" operation of iteration.

Comment: `numpy's` `unique` uses sorting to pu matching values next to each other.  You say it's easy in a compiled language.  Then can't you do the same in `numba`?  You shouldn't need python's `set` or  `dict`.

Comment: @hpaulj What would you use to test for "x in seen" without a set or dict? I suppose linear search is probably ok given the use case is likely small lists. The hard part is that len(np.unique(a)) is hard to beat when a is very large and arity 1.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, I think the numba (I will post below as a potential answer) is actually pretty good. Thanks for the idea about not using set or dict. Maybe someone will show up with another trick too.

Comment: mathtick: this is still not an MCVE, even after I added a random seed. Sampling 26 letters 1e7 times is pretty much guaranteed to quickly hit your threshold of 10 on each of the 26, so this doesn't test much. Will you please post a better MCVE?

Comment: @smci yes I've mentioned this . the hard case is all ones. I'll post that one.

Comment: You can generate S length-K strings with `[''.join(choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=K)) for _ in range(int(S))]`. Let's figure out what's a better MCVE than K=1, S=1e7.

Comment: @smci K=1 is literally the best one because it is the other extreme case. You *need* to hit everything.

Comment: And keep in mind, this isn't some "show me an implementation" as much as it is "google search is not good at this kind of thing but stack overflow is" @smci There is likely some great implementation out there that hacks it's way through numba/cython and attaches to pandas. It's plumbing and tricks. If it was raw C++ it is a trivial question basically.

Comment: @mathtick: no, K=1 is a terrible choice for testing, because there are only 26 elements in the set, and it all fits in almost zero memory, unlike say 26^K for K = 3 or4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234530/discussion-between-mathtick-and-smci).

Comment: Set is supported by Numba, but the datatype '<U1' is not. But in your case this doesn't matter, since you can create a view of the data (some integer which also has 4 Bytes) and than call the function `a=a.view(np.int32)`.

Comment: @max9111 Interesting. I had read that set was not included. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html

Comment: It is supported for a quite long time. A example from 2018 https://stackoverflow.com/a/53083946/4045774. Or something from Numba discourse: https://numba.discourse.group/t/optimization-tip-for-checking-if-a-value-is-in-an-array/506/3?u=max9111 According to your link set->All methods and operations on sets are supported in JIT-compiled functions.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj suggested, you can just use `numba` *without* a set or dict and it should be reasonable since the use case is specifically targetted for shorter lists. Obviously some regime will suffer with slow inclusion lookups.

```
import numba
        
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def nunique_truncated_numba(x_in, thresh=10):                                                            
    seen = list()
    for i, x in enumerate(x_in):
        if x not in seen:
            seen.append(x)                                                                                   
        if len(seen) > thresh:                                                                           
            return len(seen)                                                                             
    return len(seen)
```

And the *hard* case is really when you do not hit the threshold (you are using python to do vectorized sweeps).

```
In [6]: %timeit cud.nunique_truncated(b)                                                                                                                                                                           
116 µs ± 304 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit len(np.unique(b))                                                                                                                                                                                  
1.26 ms ± 2.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Would be be interested if anyone has other suggestions and tricks.